# SQL: pivot multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

**TableA**

```
ID   Qualification
1    A
2    A
3    B
```

**TableB**

```
ID   Qualification
1    C
2    A
3    A
```

Unfortunately, the names of the columns in table A and B are the same - resulting in an error 8156 - The column 'Qualification' was specified multiple times.

My select looks like follows

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (
            SELECT  A.ID, A.Qualification, B.Qualification
            FROM    TableA A LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B
                    ON      A.ID = B.ID
        )s
PIVOT
(SUM(ID) 
FOR Qualification IN ([A],[B],[C]))  pvt
```

TIA!

Comment: Depending on your desired results (which should be supplied), it could be as simple as a UNION ALL or an ALIAS

Comment: Use `union all` instead of `left join`